# How to convert word file to PDF in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activejob, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using Libreconv gem to convert word to doc but it's not working with S3

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new('bucket-name')
object = bucket.object file.attachment.blob.key
path = object.presigned_url(:get)
Libreconv.convert(path, "public/test.pdf")
```

If I try to convert this path to PDF using Libreconv then it's give me filename too long error. I have wrriten this code under ActiveJobs. So kindly provide me solutions as per ActiveJobs.

Can someone please suggest me how can I convert word file to pdf.
Here path is `https://domain.s3.amazonaws.com/Bf5qPUP3znZGCHCcTWHcR5Nn?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIZ6RZ7J425ORVUYQ%2F20181206%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181206T051240Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=b89c47a324b2aa423bf64dfb343e3b3c90dce9b54fa9fe1bc4efa9c248e912f9`

and error I am getting is

`Error: source file could not be loaded
*** Errno::ENAMETOOLONG Exception: File name too long @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/Bf5qPUP3znZGCHCcTWHcR5Nn?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIZ6RZ7J425ORVUYQ%2F20181206%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181206T051240Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=b89c47a324b2aa423bf64dfb343e3b3c90dce9b54fa9fe1bc4efa9c248e912f9.pd`

Comment: what is in `path`?

Comment: I have updated my description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> following is the answer using combine pdf gem

```
tape = Tape.new(file)
result = tape.preview
tempfile = Tempfile.new(['foo', '.pdf'])
File.open(tempfile, 'wb') do |f|
  f.write result
end
path = tempfile.path
combine_pdf(path)
```

> and for load file for S3 I have used

```
object = @bucket.object object_key
path = object.presigned_url(:get)
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(path)).body
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you PDF is created with all the params needed to fetch docx from S3.

I suppose it happens in [this line](https://github.com/FormAPI/libreconv/blob/master/lib/libreconv.rb#L36):

```
target_tmp_file = "#{target_path}/#{File.basename(@source, ".*")}.#{File.basename(@convert_to, ":*")}"
```

`@source` is `https://domain.s3.amazonaws.com/Bf5qPUP3znZGCHCcTWHcR5Nn?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIZ6RZ7J425ORVUYQ%2F20181206%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181206T051240Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=b89c47a324b2aa423bf64dfb343e3b3c90dce9b54fa9fe1bc4efa9c248e912f9` and

```
> File.basename(@source, ".*")
=> "Bf5qPUP3znZGCHCcTWHcR5Nn?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIZ6RZ7J425ORVUYQ%2F20181206%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181206T051240Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=b89c47a324b2aa423bf64dfb343e3b3c90dce9b54fa9fe1bc4efa9c248e912f9"
```

As a result Libreconv gem tries to create a tmp file with this long name and it's too long - that's why an error is raised.

Possible solution: split the process into separate steps of fetching file and converting it. Something like:

```
require "open-uri"

bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new('bucket-name')
object = bucket.object file.attachment.blob.key
path = object.presigned_url(:get)

doc_file = open(path)
begin
  Libreconv.convert(doc_file.path, "public/test.pdf")
ensure
  doc_file.delete
end
```